# Can I make a phone call in my app without an alertview popping up and return to app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplication, phone-call

I have been using:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://123456789"]];`

to make a phone call from my app and after the phone call it will return to my app.  The only problem is that I don't want to have the alertview pop up every time I have to make a call.  I have used:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://123456789"]];`

but that doesn't return to the app for me.  Is there a way I can have no alert view and have the app be returned to the foreground?

Comment: No. The alert is for security. And it is up to the user to go to whatever app they want when they finish a call. Don't forget that a user can run other apps while on a call. So automatically going back to an app at the end of a call could be disruptive.

Comment: Well `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://123456789"]];` does go back to my app when the call is done.  My question is "How can I bypass the alertview", not "How can I have my app come back after a phone call."

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `telprompt:` part. Regardless, the alert view is there for security so apps can't make secret phone calls without a user's knowledge.

Comment: But if I do `tel:` instead of `telprompt:` no alertview comes up to warn the user, so it is making a "secret" phone call.